# Backing up parameters from Octopus Deploy?

Tags: parameters, backup, octopus-deploy

Is there a way to extract or backup parameters set up in Octopus Deploy (version 3 or version 4)? Either thru an Octopus Deploy service (capability) or scripting, not from a backup database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could the [Octo.exe](https://octopus.com/docs/api-and-integration/octo.exe-command-line/export) be your answer?

For example:

```
octo export --server=https://octopusaddress/api --apiKey=API-XXXXXXXXXX --type=project --name="MyProject" --filePath=MyProject.json
```